# Why is an instance of indexing a one-dimensional array a BinaryExpression and not a MethodCallExpression?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression-trees, linq-expressions

Indexing an array, regardless of the dimensions, is a method call because it involves invoking the *indexer operator*.

Then why is the overload of the method [`System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ArrayIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.arrayindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that [takes a single array index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345296%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) made to return a `BinaryExpression` whereas its [`other overloads`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.arrayindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which represent indexing multi-dimensional arrays, are made to return `MethodCallExpression`s?

This just breaks the symmetry forcing me to remember this little anomaly. If they had made it a `MethodCallExpression`, I wouldn't have had to remember or keep note of anything.

Comment: Hmm array indexer as a method call in IL? That would make the array accessing twice slower, I see no reason for that. One-dimensional arrays are tuned for performance. Multi-dimensional arrays are not.

Comment: Thank you. I am not that educated about IL. It is one of those items on my to-do list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it's because that's what it looks like in IL. The CLI has two different kinds of arrays: *vectors* which are "rank 1, 0 lower bound" arrays, and *arrays* which are "any rank, any lower bound" arrays. (Yes, the naming is very confusing. Sorry.)

Vectors are more efficient as the runtime can do simpler arithmetic to access them. IL has specific instructions for dealing with vectors, but general array access goes through a method.

To demonstrate this, compile this code:

```
class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int[] vector = new int[10];
        int[,] array = new int[10, 10];
        int x = vector[0];
        int y = array[0, 0];
    }
}
```

Then look at it with ildasm - the last two lines of the method are compiled as:

```
// int x = vector[0]
IL_0013:  ldloc.0
IL_0014:  ldc.i4.0
IL_0015:  ldelem.i4
IL_0016:  stloc.2

// int y = array[0, 0]
IL_0017:  ldloc.1
IL_0018:  ldc.i4.0
IL_0019:  ldc.i4.0
IL_001a:  call       instance int32 int32[0...,0...]::Get(int32,
                                                          int32)
IL_001f:  stloc.3
```

So the expression tree is just representing the `ldelem` instruction as a binary operator (where the two operands are presumbly the array and the index) whereas it's using a method call for the multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Shouldn't the IL segment for `vector` include the `IL_0013:  ldloc.0` instruction?

Comment: @svick: Probably :) will fix it in a minute.